# sort File B based on column 3 of File A without changing contents of File A

Tags: linux, text-processing, files, sort, columns

I have the following file:

```
cat fileA.txt

seattle    1991  west
atlanta    1993  west
turlock    1998  west
marysville 2004  south
newyork    2007  north
canada     2004  west
```

And the second file looks like this:

```
cat fileB.txt

popular
someWhatPopular
boring
popular
popular
popular
```

I would like to get the following output on `fileB.txt`:

`popular
 popular
 popular
 someWhatPopular
 boring
 popular`

So essentially I'm trying to sort `fileB.txt` to `fileA.txt` third column

I tried the following code:

```
   #!/bin/bash
   sort -s -k3,3 fileA.txt fileB.txt
```

But it didn't work. Any suggestions? I'm pretty open to anything that doesn't require hardcoding. Bash/awk/sed, etc.

Comment: What is your algorithm for mapping {west:popular, south:someWhatPopular, north:boring}?

Comment: That is part of what I need assitance with, being able to find a way to map it that makes sense. I was thinking of looping through both files and finding contents in column 3 of File A and map them to file B, any examples or thoughts?

Comment: One sensible mapping is {north:boring, south:popular, west:someWhatPopular} since both the keys and the values are lexically sorted within their sets.

Comment: Right on. Would you have some code snippet that I could build off of? Not too familiar with bash yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a data structure issue more than linux one. You need a common entry ( key) in both tables to link them, the same as in any 'database' and it is good practice to keep a unique key in the first column of any data table. Then you can sort and link to your hearts content.

Taking something like @glennjackman mapping , you define the mapping key as being north, south etc

```
1 south somewhatPopular
2 west popular
3 north boring
4 east unexplored
```

in a file called file `popularity`. Amend `fileA` to include a unique key

```
1 seattle    1991  west
2 atlanta    1993  west
3 turlock    1998  west
4 marysville 2004  south
5 newyork    2007  north
6 canada     2004  west
```

then you can manipulate these files by `join`ing them on your selected key (in your case column 2 in `popularity` maps to column 4 in `fileA`) but `join`  needs both files to be sorted on the keyfield, so

```
join -1 4 -2 2 <(sort -k4 fileA) <(sort -k2 popularity) | sort -k2 | awk '{print $6}'

popular
popular
popular
somewhatPopular
boring
popular
```

A bit of a sledgehammer approach but it gives you most flexibility.

Break the above command at each pipe and you will see what each step does.

**Edit: Explanation of `join -1 4 -2 2    # its in the man pages`**

This tells `join` to look at the 4th column in table 1 (-1 4) and find matching values in the 2nd column of table 2 (-2 2).

`join` then composes columns from the two tables into single table but only includes the key column (north etc) once. Look at the output from

```
join -1 4 -2 2 <(sort -k4 fileA) <(sort -k2 popularity)
```

and it should be clearer

Because we had to sort the data tables for the `join` to work, we then

```
| sort -k2
```

the combined table to put them back in their original order.

The column you want is column 6 in the combined table so we just

```
| awk '{print $6}'
```

to stdout.

Comment: This is really great! I just need a brief explanation of what you are doing with the `join -1 4 -2 2 ` I understand the rest of the code, and then I will mark as correct answer! :)

Comment: Nice. The unique key for fileA doesn't contribute anything though

Comment: Not in this case but if you stick to good practice in keeping a uid in all tables then you will find it invaluable when you graduate to handling bigger and more complex data sets.

Comment: @glennjackman Just realised i was talking rubbish. I explicitly put the `fileA` uid in so the results could be sorted back to the original order. It is the uid in the `popularity` file which are redundant in this instance. I must be getting old.

Answer (score 0):

You might try to `paste` the two "table" files together, pipe the output to `sort`, then `cut` to retain only the fourth column.

Untested (cell phone right now) attempt would be something like

`paste fileA fileB | sort -s -k3,3 | cut -f4`

Answer (score 0):

You can get the alphabetical mapping with

```
paste <(awk '{print $NF}' fileA.txt | sort -u) <(sort -u fileB.txt)
```

```
north   boring
south   popular
west    someWhatPopular
```

And then a form of your desired output can be produced with awk:

```
awk '
    NR==FNR {map[$1] = $2; next} 
    {print map[$NF]}
' <(paste <(awk '{print $NF}' fileA.txt | sort -u) <(sort -u fileB.txt)) fileA.txt
```

```
someWhatPopular
someWhatPopular
someWhatPopular
popular
boring
someWhatPopular
```